# Checkbox Styling based on CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox which should look as below,

[image]

If it is not selected it should be as below,

[image]

I have the following css with me

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 10px;
  left: 24px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  line-height: 2.1ex;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
   position: absolute;
   left: -999em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -25%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #1BAAD3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

When I uncheck the checkbox this is what I can see

[image]

I'm using angular-js to handle the event of select/unselect

HTML

```
<div class="form-check">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-if="testKits" ng-model="testKits" class="form-check-input" id="testKits">
   <label class="form-check-label form-label-text source-sans-pro" for="testKits">{{'Testkits' | translate}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share html as well?

Comment: maybe you should move your `background-color: #1BAAD3;` to a new style for the `:checked` state. i.e. `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before { background-color: #1BAAD3; }` and remove it from the old style

Comment: @Hanif I have updated the post

Comment: @zgood it worked add it to answer I also added the border inside the `input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label::before {  border:1px solid #E1E5EA; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below snippet it may work for you:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 0px;
  left: 6px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  line-height: 2.1ex;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
   position: absolute;
   left: -999em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -25%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #1BAAD3;
  border: 2px solid #1BAAD3;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="testKits">
   <label class="form-check-label form-label-text source-sans-pro" for="testKits">abc</label>
</div>
```